# passing a variable from class to another class python

Tags: python, class, variables

i have a python game.py script that runs 3 stages using 3 files named stage1, stage2, stage3, and it works as it should, however on adding new features to my game when trying to get a variable from a class in stage2 to stage3 i just can not seem to get it right. The stage1 generates a var(random string name), i save the variable as machine_id here is a sample,

### Edited ## The game.py starts the 3 stages as follows below

```
class Main:

    def run_stage1(self):
        start_stage1 = stage1.Stage1() 
        unique_machine_id = start_stage1.start()
        return unique_machine_id

    def run_stage2(self):
        start_stage2 = stage2.Stage2()  
        list_of_players = start_stage2.start()  
        return list_of_players
    
    def run_stage3(self, key, path):
        start_stage3 = stage3.Game(key, path)  
        start_stage3.game_start()
```

main_folder

```
 game.py

 sub_folder
```

sub_folder

```
stage1
stage2
stage3
```

stage2 below creates a unique machine_id for each player,

```
#This is stage2

    def start_gui(machine_id): 
        root1 = tk.Tk() 
        top = Toplevel1(root1, machine_id)
        root1.mainloop()

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None, machine_id="TEST MACHINE ID"):
        self.machine_id = machine_id     
        """other code and functions below, and passing machine_id within same class i can do"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_gui("555f9f3b573f4c41e7de2c5b3f97ed54")  #Takes Machine ID As Argument
```

what i am trying to do is pass the machine id to stage3

stage 3 below.

```
#This is stage3


from sub_folder import stage2        #<- imported stage2

class Stage3:
    def __init__(self):
        fetch_var_machine_id = stage2.Toplevel1(self, machine_id)  # << This is what i am using but it does not pass the variable.
        print(fetch_var_machine_id)  # <This Just Returns 'S' Not the machine_id

    def start(self, fetch_var_machine_id):
        """Do stuff"""
        return """Do Stuff"""
```

This is an example of how i have been trying to pass the Machine id from one class to another without success. i can not seem to understand with other tutorials

Comment: Where is `Stage3` instantiated? Edit the question.

Comment: from the main game.py file as edited above. calling the tkinter top does not seem necessary.

Comment: After you call `run_stage1` what do you do with the result? You need to pass it to `Stage3` (which you seem to have renamed `Game`). See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Read the [tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `Stage3` instance you need to pass `top` as an initialisation parameter:

```
top = ...
stage3 = Stage3(top)
```

So you need to add that to your class definition:

```
class Stage3:
    def __init__(self, top):
        print(top.machine_id)
```

Comment: thanks for your response however i can not get this to work. More so i do not understand.         top = ...
stage3 = Stage3(top)

Comment: I mean by `...` that the code is the same as it is in your example above, then you add the `stage3` line below it.

Comment: Please answer the question I asked about where you instantiate `Stage3`. Please edit your question.